# How does SSH used for dynamic port forwarding know where a request wants to go?

Tags: ssh, proxy, port-forwarding, socks

Dynamic port forwarding using SSH uses SOCKS protocol. How does SSH know where a request wants to go? For example if the request is a HTTP request, SSH doesn't understand HTTP, so where  does it find out where the HTTP request wants to go? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't.  It creates a SOCKS proxy and the *client* talks the SOCKS protocol to say what it needs to do.   There are no "http" requests at this layer.

The web browser speaks "SOCKS" language to say 'connect me to XYZ' and once the connection is made *then* it speaks HTTP (or HTTPS) to the remote server.

Similarly, a SOCKS aware SMTP client could talk SOCKS and say 'connect me to ABC' and then speaks SMTP.